Union of Lattices (Hasse diagrams)
I am a little bit confused between creating a glue or a union of lattices. what is the difference between "glue" and "union" when talking about lattices.
I know that the glue is just placing the lattices above eachother. is that the same when taking their union?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
